# apending to an array in a cache file without re-writing the whole file

Tags: php, arrays, caching, multidimensional-array

So I have a file called cache, which stores traffic analysis of a site, using multidimensional arrays.

cache.php

```
$traffic_array=array("date_ip_uniqueNU"=>array("pageviews"=>34,"time_enteredOnsite"=>"12:00"),"date_ip_uniqueNU"=>array("pageviews"=>34,"time_enteredOnsite"=>"12:00"));//ect ect
```

Now, I need to somehow append to the array above.

I could simply just read the whole file, go through and rebuild the array in a foreach loop, and then just re-write the whole file, something like this:

```
include('cache.php');

foreach($traffic_array as $mainKey){

$rebuild_contents.="array("something"=>array("pageviews"=>".$mainKey['pageviews'].","time_enteredOnsite"=>".$mainKey['time_enteredOnsite'].");"//so I'm just building a string containing all the code to re-write the file.

} 

//then write to the file

$file="cache.php";

$content_to_put"\<? \$traffic_array=\"$rebuild_content\";"

file_put_contents($file,$content_to_put);

//NOTE: I just quickly wrote this up now, so expect syntax errors.
```

So do you see what I've done above - Simply rebuild the array contents into a string, and then write that string into the cache file.

But, I'm sure there is a much better approach to this, so can someone help me out?

Thank you! xD

EDIT: Also a problem with the method above, If this process was to happen multiple times, at the EXACT same millisecond - something would mess up, right?

Comment: ad edit: Yes. Use `flock()` to prevent that

Comment: @Robus That's interesting - So How would I check if the file is already in use?

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very, hm, strange method of caching.
Let suppose that you wish to change some php code in the file.

file_put_contents have ability to append the data to end of file, call this method with flag FILE_APPEND ([details](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)).
You may change method of defining array to like this:

```
$traffic_array[new key 1] = array(new data 1);
$traffic_array[new key 2] = array(new data 2);
...
```

And then you just add content to end of file like this

```
file_put_contents($file, '$traffic_array[your new key] = array(data for adding);', FILE_APPEND);
```

But if you may not change method of defining the array traffic_array then file_put_contents not for you. Use `fopen()` with flag 'r+', use `fseek()` for move a pointer to to correct place for put new data at the file, `fwrite()` for write only new data, and `fclose()`.

```
// Content of file: <?php $a = array('k' => array(), 'k2' => array());\n
$f = fopen('file', 'r+');
fseek($f, -3, SEEK_END); // place the pointer after last value of array, before ");\n"; cont from end
fwrite($f, ", 'k3' => array('f'=>'a'));\n"); // put new data, also add overwrited data ");\n"
fclose($f);
//now content of file: <?php $a = array('k' => array(), 'k2' => array(), 'k3' => array('f'=>'a'));\n
```

Changing of input file can cause huge problems.

> Also a problem with the method above, If this process was to happen multiple times, at the EXACT same millisecond - something would mess up, right?

Right, read about file locking.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a great way of cacheing, simply because you're having to ask this question. It ought to be easy to add a new entry.

My advice is to either:

1. use a database table called cache and either add new rows or retrieve, alter and write just one row as you need to.

   Or
2. Use a file that doesn't contain PHP code, but something else like CSV, where you can easily append to it without having to worry about closing semicolons etc, and you can also read it quickly using built in PHP library functions like fgetcsv() when you need to.